# android- putParcelableArrayList in CountDownTimer put same value on List returned

Tags: android

I try to get val from AudioRecord in a countDown but when I get the list extra in the Activity, contains same value (I have already checked that AudioRecord returns me differents values). Please help me!. Thanks in advance.
Note: I call the countDown passing it 45 * 1000 and 100

```
// Class of CountDownTimer
dataValues = new ArrayList<Data>();
(MenuActivity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new CountDownTimer(millis, intervalInMillis){
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        firstValues.add(val); // val from AudioRecord
                   if (firstValues.size() >=10){
                        firstValues.remove(0);
                        data.setValue(avgFromIntList(firstValues));
                        data.setTime(new Date().getTime());
                        dataValues.add(data);

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    Bundle extras = new Bundle();

                    extras.putLong("idSession", session.getId());
                    extras.putParcelableArrayList("values",dataValues);

                    Intent toPast = new Intent(context, SessionPastActivity.class);
                    toPast.putExtras(extras);
                    context.startActivity(toPast);

                }
            }.start();
        }
    });


// Model class that implement Parcelable
```

public class Data implements Parcelable {

```
private Integer value; 
private Long time;

public Data(Integer value, Long time) {
    this.value = value;
    this.time = time;
}

public Data() {
}



public Integer getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(Integer value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public Long getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(Long time) {
    this.time = time;
}



@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Data{" +
            ", value=" + value +
            ", time=" + time +
            '}';
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

    dest.writeInt(value);
    dest.writeLong(time);

    Log.e("inWrite", toString());
}

// this is used to regenerate your object. All Parcelables must have a CREATOR that implements these two methods
public static final Parcelable.Creator<Data> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Data>() {
    public Data createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Data(in);
    }

    public Data[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Data[size];
    }
};

// example constructor that takes a Parcel and gives you an object populated with it's values
private Data(Parcel in) {

    value = in.readInt();
    time = in.readLong();

    Log.e("inREAD", toString());
}
```

// Activity class

ArrayList  values_amplitude =  getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayList("values");

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Bundle bundle=getIntent.getExtra();

    if(bundle != null){
    ArrayList<Data> values_amplitude = (ArrayList<Data>).getParcelable("values");
    } else {}
```

Hope it will work for you

Comment: don't work, throw this error: Key values expected Parcelable but value was a java.util.ArrayList.  The default value <null> was returned.

                                                                 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable

Comment: pass Value like this                    \   Intent toPast = new Intent(context, SessionPastActivity.class);
                    toPast.putExtra("idSession", session.getId());
                    toPast .putExtra("values",dataValues);
                   
                    context.startActivity(toPast);